# SSH Tunnel with Android

Tags: ssh, vnc

Without rooting, how can I SSH tunnel to my homePC running sshd?

I need ssh tunnel to VNC home, but i don't trust VNC, so I want to use it with SSH to make it safe!

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to connect to your home PC from your phone, there is [ConnectBot](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.connectbot)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [QuickSSHd](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.quicksshd) - it claims "root" is optional, but I don't know whether it'll work with what you're trying to achieve.

There's also the quite popular [ConnectBot](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.connectbot) which should allow you to tunnel in to your PC.